# Failing SQL Server Cluster installation, Addnode: Remote registry call failed

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, sql-server-2012, sql-server-cluster

I'm adding a node to a SQL Server failover cluster. The installer throws the error "Addnode: Remote registry call failed. Unable to retrieve primary node Filestream settings" when adding node two

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1 Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> Addnode: Remote registry call failed. Unable to retrieve primary node
>   Filestream settings
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.3128.0&EvtType=0xB04B8EB8%25400x4BDAF9BA%25401306%254032

The os on the servers are Windows 2012. Any advice where to start looking?

Thanks

Comment: Is the remote registry service configured and started on both cluster members?

Comment: To add to what @pauska mentioned I would check if node two has permission to access node 1 registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a combination of missconfigurations. First of all, thanks @pauska. I had to enable the Remote Registry Service but also enable the Filestream on my first node.

[image]